# Creating a weatherapp, following a githubproject, how can I get the tempetaure in celsius instead of fahrenheit?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyWeather.Forms

This is the project that I am currently using and it works perfectly. As I explain in my title I am trying to get the degrees in celsius instead of fahrenheit but I have not yet figured it out.

Maybe it is not even possible but when I examine the code I see a line that looks like this:

```
var unit = IsImperial ? "F" : "C";
            Temp = $"Temp: {weatherRoot?.MainWeather?.Temperature ?? 0}°{unit}";
            Condition = $"{weatherRoot.Name}: {weatherRoot?.Weather?[0]?.Description ?? string.Empty}";
```

Does `var unit = IsImperial ? "F" : "C";` mean F as in fahrenheit and C as in celsius?

Comment: yes as unit will get inserted after the degrees sign in the Temp string where it says °{unit} that will become °C or °F depending on the value of IsImperial

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/36/conditional-operator/153/conditionally-assign-a-value-to-a-variable#t=201607211835398138022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer answer this question:

> Does var unit = IsImperial ? "F" : "C"; mean F as in fahrenheit and C as in celsius?

It is in Ternary operator format. It is essentially the equivalent of

```
string unit = String.Empty;
if(IsImperial == true){
    unit = "F"
}else{
    unit = "C"
}
```

It is just storing a string for later use to say something like "50 F" or "50 C", where F and C are equal to the variable unit;

if you need to have your app use metric units, celcius, somewhere early in the app (maybe on app load?) set **Helpers.Settings.IsImperial = false**. You do NOT have to manually convert the temperatures because the call to a rest api will do that for you. This app is set up to handle everything like that for you sicne it is just displaying the temperature, in EITHER celcius fahrenheit for you.

**EDIT**: is what I did

```
public App()
{
        Helpers.Settings.IsImperial = false;
.....
}
```

Comment: Setting it to false immediately inside App.cs but it does not find `IsImperial`. with this line of code that you mentioned: `Helpers.Settings.IsImperial = false;`

Comment: Changed it to; Weather.Settings.IsImperial = false; instead. Works! Cheers and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes as unit will get inserted after the degrees sign in the Temp string where it says `°{unit}` that will become `°C` or `°F` depending on the value of IsImperial.

To get the temperature in celsius you can just say

```
var temp = weatherRoot?.MainWeather?.Temperature ?? 0;
if(IsImperial)
  temp = (temp - 32) * 1.8;
```

Comment: I changed it to this but I still recieve it as fahrenheit. Inside Weather.cs file, the line: `public string DisplayTemp => $"Temp: {MainWeather?.Temperature ?? 0}° {Weather?[0]?.Main ?? string.Empty}";` Do I have to adjust that one as well in order to make it work?

Comment: put this near the top and then replace `MainWeather?.Temperature` with `temp` everywhere

Comment: @Slepz, no conversion or MainWeather?.Temperature code is necessary. OP Simply needs to set Settings.IsImperial early in the app to false to get Celcius

Comment: @Benji Oh I thought IsImperial was something he was getting out of the JSON he was receiving

Comment: @Slepz nah, looking through the code there is a helper class to handle settings. Depending on the value of Settings.IsImperial a call to a rest api will pass either "Imperial" or "Metric" as a query string value and return the proper number

Comment: `bool isImperial = Settings.IsImperial;
  public bool IsImperial
  {
   get { return isImperial; }
   set
   {
    isImperial = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    Settings.IsImperial = value;
   }
  }` so i have to adjust the code inside here then if i understand correctly

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a bit of a quick look through the project and I didn't see an actual conversion function so the request likely handles it

The code that you've linked is just display code within the viewmodel. This is really only a string formatting line to display it on the UI. If you look at the lines above it you can see:

```
//Get forecast based on cityId
Forecast = await WeatherService.GetForecast(weatherRoot.CityId, units);
```

This is what actually makes the request to the server and units is set a little above that with:

```
var units = IsImperial ? Units.Imperial : Units.Metric;
```

So IsImperial being set to false would *Likely* change the format of your request so that you'll receive the results in Metric. As to if F means Fahrenheit and C means Celsius -- Yes. The line below that expands to °{unit}

The line you quoted is just using a ternary if. Just a bit of syntactic sugar that expands to:

```
string unit;
if (IsImperial)
    unit = "F"
else 
    unit = "C"
```

Comment: At some point early in the app he needs to set the Settings.IsImperial value to false (it's a static property, so no instantiaion needed)

Comment: I would love to see an example of that Benji. Where to put it exactly. That would save some time to make this work

Comment: @medvedo It looks to me like its set in MyWeather/Helpers/Settings.cs from the app settings. Just look for places that Settings.IsImperial is set. If you want to force it to Celsius for your use only then you can just have it always return false.

Comment: Yes precisely! Easier fix than I thought. Thanks alot for the help